# How can I pass the list of columns returned by the dbt_utils.star function to the snapshot check_cols paramter?

Tags: postgresql, jinja2, dbt

I'm using snapshots in my dbt project to track changes to column values, but there are a few columns which I expect to change regularly. My tables have a ton of columns, so I'd like to come up with a way to pass a list of columns using something like the dbt_utils.star functions with an except statement to achieve this. Here's where I'm at:

```
{% snapshot _patient_active_medication_history %}

    {{
        config(
          strategy='check',
          unique_key='source_id',
          tags=['osmind_deid'],
          check_cols=dbt_utils.star(
            ref("_patient_active_medication_update"), 
            except=["_dbt_built_at", "_git_commit_id"]
            ) | list
        )
    }}
    
    select * from {{ ref('_patient_active_medication_update') }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

When I  run this code it works, but it's interpretting the result of dbt_utils.star as '*'. My guess is this has to do with the order in which the dbt_utils.star function is evaluating. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Appreciate any help.

I've tried listing out all of the columns from the table as a list, and that gives the desired effect, but this is something I need to implement across 20+ tables, each with ~20 columns... So i'd like to find a way to automate this.

Comment: Use `| split(", ")` to split at each comma instead of `| list` to convert the string into a character array.